# Passing arguments to powershell 7 script invoked form powershell 5

Tags: bash, powershell

I am running this script from powershell 5:

```
pwsh.exe -command {
    Import-Module PoshGram
    $token = "some_token"
    $chat = "-some_id"
    Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat -Message $args[0]
}
```

pwsh.exe is powershell 7.

This script is saved in a file as sendnotif.ps1 and is run from powershell 5 in this way:

```
> sendnotif.ps1 "hello"
```

But "hello" argument is not captured withing powershell 7 command. Its empty. Can someone please help me to capture this argument from powershell 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two levels of `args`. Your first code block is inside the script and you call the script with an `$arg = "hello"` inside your script `$arg` itself is not used. But One level deeper in the `pwsh` instance you try to use `$arg[0]` that has never been provided to this script block:

```
pwsh.exe -command {
    Import-Module PoshGram
    $token = "some_token"
    $chat = "-some_id"
    Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat -Message $args[0]
}
```

Doesn't get any `$args` so add them >

```
pwsh.exe -command {
    Import-Module PoshGram
    $token = "some_token"
    $chat = "-some_id"
    Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat -Message $args[0]
} -args $args # $args are the args from outside the script
```

That is a whole lot of `$args` I hope you understand what I am trying to tell you...